# Why does assigning to this ivar have no effect?

Tags: objective-c, synthesize

I have a class, `BPGameEngine`, with a readonly property, `currCharacter`. In the past, I had been assigning to the ivar directly (like `_currCharacter = someCharacter;`) inside `BPGameEngine`. In a subclass I found myself needing to write to this property, and therefore redeclared it in an anonymous category like so

```
@interface BPGameKitMPGameEngine()

    @property (readwrite, assign) BPCharacterInstance* currCharacter;

@end
```

The compiler then had an error (which, bizarrely, I can't reproduce anymore, two days later), which alluded to needing an @synthesize statement, so I added `@synthesize currCharacter = _currCharacter;` in the subclass (`BPGameKitMPEngine`).

I did *not* add a similar anonymous category in the superclass, because I was just using the iVar directly. I then discovered that the line `_currCharacter = someCharacter;` which is inside a method of `BPGameEngine` called by `BPGameKitMPEngine` in a call to super (`[super methodContainingAssignmentToCurCharIvar]`) *simply did nothing*. `_currCharacter` showed up in the debugger, and `someCharacter` was not nil, but after the line was executed, `_currCharacter` remained `nil`. Bizarrely, adding a similar anonymous category in the subclass fixed the problem, as did removing the `@synthesize` (which no longer causes Xcode to complain of compiler errors).

The inconsistent requirement for an `@synthesize` seems like it must be a bug in Xcode, but the rest of this has me stumped. Can someone explain the problem with having the `@synthesize` in the subclass?

Comment: Why is your object property `assign`? Are you not using ARC?

Comment: I am indeed not using ARC.

Comment: Where's the declaration of the original readonly property? In the superclass's main interface?

Comment: Yes, its in BPGameEngine's .h file.

Comment: You should have been getting a compiler error about reusing a private ivar at some point in this process. I'm puzzled. This seems inconsistent to me: « therefore redeclared it in an anonymous category like so

@interface BPGameKitMPGameEngine()» and «I did not add a similar anonymous category in the subclass».  Isn't the BPGameKitMPGameEngine the subclass?

Comment: Oh, that's a typo. Sorry for the confusion, I meant the superclass.

Comment: I believe there's two ivars being created. I'm just not sure how. The relevant code has this structure? https://gist.github.com/woolsweater/47f0fd43d2ac114e8ee5

Comment: Yes that's the same structure. The only difference (which is probably irrelevant) is that the methods where this is happening are init methods (the superclass's init calls the subclasses').

Comment: The superclass's init calls the subclass's?! You mean that the other way around, right? This does not make sense. The code in that gist doesn't compile, and neither should yours. I must be missing something. Can you cut down your code to a minimal example and put it into your question, please?

Comment: Gah. Sorry to keep confusing you with typos.... it is the *subclass* calling the *superclass*.

Comment: I think Xcode is the one missing something.... So I copy pasted your project into a single file and, as you said, there is a compiler error... But if you break it up into separate .h's and .m's for each class, it compile with no errors.

Comment: @BenPious Just to clarify, although the syntax may look like an 'anonymous category' what you're declaring is actually a *class extension*, which is something quite different. Objective-C doesn't support declaring instance variables in categories.

Answer (score 2):

An auto synthesised instance variable backing a property is private to the class it is created in. Therefore you cannot (directly) extend a read-only property to read-write one in a subclass - there is no access to original instance variable.

You should get various errors, such as ones pointing out you cannot access a private instance variable from your superclass if you try this. It sounds like you may have managed to create two properties, each with their own backing variable, hence a change to one is not as a change to the other - but how you managed that in this case I've no idea.

Of course you can bypass the private access... the following should work:

```
@interface BPGameKitMPGameEngine ()

   - (void) setCurrCharacter:(int)value;

@end
```

and:

```
- (void) setCurrCharacter:(BPCharacterInstance *)value
{
   [self setValue:value forKey:@"_currCharacter"];
}
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks. The core of the issue, apart from my misunderstanding from another question that redeclaring the variable inside the superclass that originally declared it as readwrite != redeclaring inside of a subclass as readwrite (Thanks for clearing that up), seems to have been that Xcode doesn't actually give the warning about using an ivar in the superclass unless all the implementations and interfaces are in the same file, leading me to believe that that @synthesize wasn't making another ivar.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I did understand you problem 100% but please do the following:

- Create a new class extension file for `BPGameKitMPGameEngine` called `Private`.
- Import that file (`#import "BPGameKitMPGameEngine_Private.h"`) into `BPGameKitMPGameEngine.m` and `BPGameKitMPEngine.m`.
- Remove the existing class extension code from `BPGameKitMPGameEngine`.

And now check if it works as you would expect.